# Using javascript to change rgb value of background onclick

Tags: javascript, background-color

I'm trying to implement a very simple JavaScript program: every time you click the button, the  RGB values of the background color are randomized.

Here's the Javascript:

```
function change() {
    var x = Math.floor(Math.random() * 256); // range is 0-255
    var y = Math.floor(Math.random() * 256);
    var z = Math.floor(Math.random() * 256);
    var thergb = "'rgb(" + x + "," + y + "," + z + ")'"; 
    console.log(thergb);
    document.body.style.background=thergb;
}
```

I'm pretty sure the problem is in how I hack together the `thergb` variable, but there are no errors in the console so I'm not quite sure. I log the console just to make sure it's giving me an actual random rgb, which it is.

Here's the full JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/L92bY/

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/L92bY/8/

Comment: There is error in the console - "change is not defined" ;) (in your fiddle) btw you have an extra "'".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have wrapped it in `'` .. why ?

If you remove that it works..

```
var thergb = "rgb(" + x + "," + y + "," + z + ")";
```

Demo at http://jsfiddle.net/gaby/L92bY/9/

(*you also needed to define the `change` function in the `head` tag and not in the `onLoad` event..*)

Comment: I wrapped it because if I just do `document.body.style.background="rgb(4,5,23)"` for example, it only works with the quotes. Why don't I need them now?

Comment: @user1925805 You need one kind of quote around it to signify that it is a string.. but you have used both `"` and `'` quotes..

Comment: I see, my mistake was thinking I needed to replicate everything past the `=` in the variable, including the quotes.

Answer (score 2):

The CSS syntax for an `rgb()` value does not include single quotes.

Change `'rgb(x,y,z)'` to `rgb(x,y,z)`.

Answer (score 0):

Two things:

1. You need to choose one of the "nowrap" options for where the fiddle server puts your code.
2. You need to get rid of the single-quote characters around your "rgb()" expression.

   ```
       var thergb = "rgb(" + x + "," + y + "," + z + ")";
   ```

Personally I'd set "backgroundColor" instead of just "background", but it works (in Firefox at least) to set "background".

[Fixed fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/4sufU/)

Answer (score 0):

Working fiddle (just corrected your code): http://jsfiddle.net/L92bY/18/

The syntax for the CSS color as rgb is `rgb(r,g,b)` (no extra apostrophe "`'`") = not <strike>`'rgb(r,g,b)'`</strike>

```
function change() {
    var x = Math.floor(Math.random() * 256); // range is 0-255
    var y = Math.floor(Math.random() * 256);
    var z = Math.floor(Math.random() * 256);
    var thergb = "rgb(" + x + "," + y + "," + z + ")"; 
    console.log(thergb);
    document.body.style.background=thergb;
}
```

PS: If this is not working for you you are calling this javascript function BEFORE it was declared.

Answer (score 0):

You could probably also just simplify where your code went wrong by using string template literals.

```
var thergb = `rgb(${x}, ${y}, ${z})`
```